# NSView alignmentRectForFrame: on OS X 10.6

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspopupbutton

Since 10.7 `NSVeiw` has new method called [`alignmentRectForFrame:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/alignmentRectForFrame%3a) that returns `NSRect` of actual content (excluding borders, shadows, reflections ...).

Is there an alternative methon or workaround on 10.6?

Details: I am creating `NSPopUpButton` with a list (`NSMenu`) containing `NSImage`s as items. The problem is that, by default, images in `NSMenu` have the original size, but the selected one (seen in `NSPopUpButton`) is rescaled. I would like images to be the same size both in `NSMenu` and `NSPopUpButton`.